# How do I filter rows of an array so that only records with a particular value are displayed?

Tags: php, arrays, filter

Imagine I am running 2 queries each one against a different database.

The query result from source #1 will be stored in an array.
The query result from source #2 will also be stored in an array.

Source #2 records will contain a foreign key that may or may not match up with particular records in an ID field in source #1.

So if I were to loop through source #1 and then I wanted to display only the source #2 records that matched the ID of source #1 is there a handy command within PHP that will allow me to get the filtered results that I could run once each time I ran the loop.

What I would like to avoid is having a loop within a loop to check the result before determining if it should be displayed (hopefully a built in filter command if available will have less overhead).

Any suggestions on commands that filter an array within PHP?

Comment: Are those two databases within the same physical server instance? You can run queries/joins across database boundaries in some SQL servers, like MySQL. "select databasename.tablename.fieldname from ..." is fully functional syntax. If that's the case, you can join the tables at the database level and leave PHP to just display the results.

Comment: It would be nice to have a [mcve] here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A row in a given array is either an object or an array. We cannot run array_intersect on the entire result array because array elements are not scalar values.

I would create one loop to store the primary key indices, then call array_filter on it in which the function would check for a valid correspondence.

```
global $aIds;
$aIds = array();

foreach($array_masters  as $item) {
    $aIds[] = $item->master_id;
}

function filter_correspondant($row) {
    global $aIds;
    return in_array($row->slave_id, $aIds);
}

$array_slaves_filtered = array_filter($array_slaves, 'filter_correspondant');
```

In the above snippet, the two arrays are $array_masters and $array_slaves. The resulting intersected array is $array_slaves_filtered which contains rows from $array_slaves that match the foreign key constraint.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what you're optimizing for.

- Lines of code: use array_intersect as mentioned by Matt V (possibly after some preprocessing).
- Memory / performance: create a dictionary (associative array) where the keys are the IDs of source #1. If memory is a concern, discard the rows once they are processed. Values can be anything, say TRUE. You can now filter the array from source #2 using `isset($dict[$id])`, which runs in near constant time. `array_filter` can be useful here.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like a job for [array_intersect](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php).